# How can we get all the nodes name from unknown XML throught java

Tags: java, xml, string

Suppose My XML Looks like This

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employees>
<Employee>
    <name>Pankaj</name>
    <age>29</age>
    <role>Java Developer</role>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <address>
       <flat>f 09</flat>
       <housenum>naksha atlantis</housenum>
       <area>E city</area>
    </address>
    <ContactDetails>
        <mobile>4676543565</mobile>
        <landline>0120-223312</landline>
    </ContactDetails>
</Employee>
</Employee>
    <Employee>
    <name>Lisa</name>
    <age>35</age>
    <role>CSS Developer</role>
    <gender>Female</gender>
    <addressLine>
       <local>f 03</local>
       <gate>149</gate>
       <area>domlur</area>
    </addressLine>
 </Employee>
</Employees>


**I want output in this format**
```

**[Employees[Employee[name,age,role,gender,address[flat,housenum,area],ContactDetails[mobile,landline]]]]
[Employees[Employee[name,age,role,gender,,addressLine2[local2,gate2,area2]]]]**##

Comment: I would suggest to implement a Domain Specific Language (DLS) to parse the XML document into a Syntax Tree with the output you need.
ANTLR4 is one of the most used DLS tools and w3 is plenty of documentation about it. The most interesting reading about ANTLR4 is The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference, by Terrence Parr with some simple examples of parsing XML document

Answer (score 0):

I would use Java SAX and log element name in every `startElement` event.

A nice example can be found [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/).

Answer (score 0):

Look out, your example XML is not properly formatted due to duplicated `</Employee>` tag after first employee.

---

Assuming you don't know the XML schema and the XML can be loaded into the  memory you can use [Dom4j](https://dom4j.github.io/) and create a recursive function to inspect the elements:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    Document doc = reader.read(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/input.xml"));
    iterate(doc.getRootElement(), 0);
}

private static void iterate(Element el, int level) {
    System.out.print(" ".repeat(level));
    System.out.println(el.getName());
    el.elements().forEach(e -> iterate(e, level + 1));
}
```

will output:

```
Employees
 Employee
  name
  age
  role
  gender
  address
   flat
   housenum
   area
  ContactDetails
   mobile
   landline
 Employee
  name
  age
  role
  gender
  addressLine
   local
   gate
   area
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use org.w3c.dom which is included in JDK1.4 and above and do something like this:

```
private static String parse(Node n) {
    if(n.getChildNodes().getLength() <= 2) return n.getNodeName();
    String res = n.getNodeName() + "[";
    NodeList children = n.getChildNodes();
    for(int i = 1 ; i < children.getLength() ; i += 2) {
        res += parse(children.item(i)) + ",";
    }
    return res.substring(0, res.length() - 1) + "]";
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("data.xml"));
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("[" + parse(doc.getFirstChild()) + "]");
}
```

which gives the output:

```
Employees[Employee[name,age,role,gender,address[flat,housenum,area],ContactDetails[mobile,landline]],Employee[name,age,role,gender,addressLine[local,gate,area]]]]
```